# Disabling pathauto in a production drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

If I disable pathauto in my Drupal installation, am I going to have any issue with my Drupal website ?

It simply display a meaningful url for each node and it can disable at any moment. Correct ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont have any technical issues not using path_auto, but you should consider what you will do with search engines. Renaming all of your urls will cost page rank, even with redirects.

Comment: Are you sure removing pathauto will rename the URLs?  Pathauto simply generates the path and adds it to the path DB.

Comment: If your meaning-ful url's are gone then they would generate 404, you'd lose your PR quickly. If the site is used within company itself, then no side affects.